# Firebase high background data usage on android

Tags: android, firebase

I am using firebase for a school dashboard application. The application is built using android. It logs in via google credentials to firebase. Disk persistence is enabled on firebase. There are no other services or connections that the app uses. Firebase version set in build is 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0+'

I opened the app - it logs in and gets the data - then put it in background. The data usage looks like the following -

Foreground data usage stays steady at - 38.87kb

Background data usage keeps increasing every few minutes - 2.53kb, 2.94kb, 11.49kb, 11.9kb, 12.18kb, 12.59kb, 13.90kb, 67kb, 92kb. It is consuming about 1.5kb of data every minute.

I've made sure all firebase listeners are disconnected on pause. Why is the application background data usage continuously increasing over time?

Answer (score 3):

The Firebase client keeps a network connection open to its servers. As part of keeping this connection, the client and server occasionally exchange keep-alive messages. These will likely use some memory, which should be (largely) reclaimed upon a garbage collection.

You might want to upgrade to the latest version of the Firebase SDK for Android btw. It's now on version 2.5.2.

Comment: The problem is the messages seem to be exchanged very frequently, and continue as long as the app is in background, irrespective to time elapsed. Is there way to reduce this, perhaps via config. Or, close the connection after a certain period of inactivity. Over a period of a month this is resulting in data usage of many MBs from the app being in background, while the foreground is much less over the same period of time - here is some actual data usage by the app from beta test- 
Tablet1 - foreground data usage 413KB, background data usage 4.30MB.

Comment: Problem isn't memory usage, but, network and battery usage as a result of the connection being left open in background.

Answer (score 1):

I just found 2 methods on Firebase class - goOffline() and goOnline() that might help me reduce the background data usage. I am going to try them in onPause, and onResume for all the activities in the app.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done to reduce data usage is create a service that mantain a reference counted state of when firebase is needed to be online and use goOnline()/goOffline() according that state:

```
class OnlineTracker {
   void onlineNeeded(); //Increase reference count
   void releaseOnlineNeeded(); //Decrease reference count
}
```

And when you need to do operations that requiere Firebase to be online you do:

```
try {
    OnlineTracker.onlineNeeded();
    ...
    Firebase operations that need online status
    ...
} finally {
    OnlineTracker.releaseOnline()
}
```

That way when OnlineTracker has reference count>0 it calls goOnline() and when it returns to 0 it calls goOffline();

To prevent too much switching you can also delay when you goOffline and wait some time to see if online needed status will be needed in very small time.

[See this gist for complete real code](https://gist.github.com/lujop/ba480de9ad061a99758ff5cebcc10cec)